# How to Optimize my JOIN's to speed up my Query?

Tags: mysql

I have 6 queries like the following query listed below..

- each are taking 6 seconds to run
- for a total of 36 seconds for page to load

Is there a way to optimize these kinds of queries?

```
SELECT
tickets.ticketID,
tickets.ticket,
tickets.name1,
tickets.address1,
tickets.city,
tickets.cstate,
tickets.zip,
tickets.caller_type,
tickets.phone,
tickets.caller,
tickets.caller_phone,
tickets.contact,
tickets.contact_phone,
tickets.call_back,
tickets.location,
tickets.printable_text,
tblnotes.ntDate,
tblnotes.ntText,
tblstatus.stDesc,
tblUsers.username 
FROM tblusers
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tickets ON tblusers.ID = tickets.ownerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblstatus ON tblstatus.stID = tickets.statusID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblnotes ON tblnotes.ntID = tickets.noteID 
WHERE tblstatus.stDesc <> "Closed"
```

Comment: How big are the tables?  Is there an index on `tblstatus.stDesc`?

Comment: The query itself is very simple and cannot be optimized. You must ensure that you have indexes on all columns used in the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Is the database server itself running optimized?  Does it have enough RAM?  Do block sizes line up?

Comment: Can we assume that the `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY` relationships are correctly defined?

Comment: Do you really need to use the RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN's? Because the RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN's requires more scanning then three INNER JOIN's

Comment: The condition in the WHERE clause, restricting to non-NULL values of `stDesc` from `tblstatus` renders the outer join equivalent to an inner join. For an outer join, relocate that condition from the WHERE  clause to the ON clause. Otherwise, remove `LEFT OUTER` from before `JOIN tblstatus`.

Comment: Yes, I do have all ID fields indexed. There are about 150,000 records in the tickets table. The MySQL server has 24 gig ram.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: try this

```
SELECT
tickets.ticketID,
tickets.ticket,
tickets.name1,
tickets.address1,
tickets.city,
tickets.cstate,
tickets.zip,
tickets.caller_type,
tickets.phone,
tickets.caller,
tickets.caller_phone,
tickets.contact,
tickets.contact_phone,
tickets.call_back,
tickets.location,
tickets.printable_text,
tblnotes.ntDate,
tblnotes.ntText,
tblstatus.stDesc,
tblUsers.username 
FROM tickets
INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.ID = tickets.ownerID
INNER JOIN tblstatus ON tblstatus.stID = tickets.statusID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblnotes ON tblnotes.ntID = tickets.noteID 
WHERE tickets.statusID <> 3
```

posting as an answer, as I am unable to comment

You have a condition `where tblstatus.stDesc <> "Closed"`

assuming you have an index here on stID
change that to  `where tblstatus.stID <> put the id value`

also change your left outer joins to inner joins, as any ways you have a where condition, you can keep the left join on `tblnotes` as I am not sure if it may have a row corresponding to `tbltickets`

i will also move the `tickets` table to `from` and then do an inner join with `tblusers`

use `left outer join` only when the join table may not have data, but you still want to show data from your main table

Comment: I changed the WHERE clause to be: WHERE tickets.statusID <> 3 but it didn't make any difference.